# How can I measure thread waiting time?

Tags: java, multithreading, measure

I couldn't find out how to measure the time that a Thread is waiting locked. I have to determine if a Thread is waiting locked more than 1 second and if so to run another Thread instead. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you care if it is locked? If a thread takes more than 1 second for any reason you could start another thread or you could use an ExecutorService and let it create the threads for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
methodToTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

Comment: @Combine If it is useful for you please accept it as a right answer.. :)

Comment: I would do so but I don't have the credits to rate or choose right answer :)                                                    Sooner or later I will. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Time it using `Sytem.nanoTime();` just before and after the wait.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
wait();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start; // nanos
```

Or:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
synchronized (objHere)
{
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start; // nanos
    // ...
}
```

---

**Note**: If a Thread is locked, the scheduler will continue with other Threads. You don't have to do this manually. That is the idea of threads. Maybe you are facing a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)? Wikipedia says it nicely:

> A deadlock is a situation in which two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the methods which operates on locks accepts timeout as an argument. If you are using wait(), you can specify the amount of time by passing time to wait as argument. Check here for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29.

If you are using Lock, then try tryLock method of it which accepts time it has to wait. Check this tutorial for an idea: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html