# In Java, Is there a way to get the actual waiting time of a Thread after notify it

Tags: java, multithreading

If I use `wait()` function to put a thread in wait for 20 seconds, then I notify this thread with another thread before it finishes waiting. Can I possibly get the actual waiting time?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382971/how-can-i-measure-thread-waiting-time

Comment: [`Object.wait(long timeout)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) returns `void`, so it's not possible without writing additional code.

Comment: Look at the time-of-day before and after the wait.

Comment: @Villat that seems to be working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this would be starting a stopwatch before the wait and see how long it took until the thread proceed:

```
Object ob;

public void waitingThread(){
    try {
        Long before =System.nanoTime();
        ob.wait(20);
        long waitTime = System.nanoTime() - before;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the wait without the [loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())